# fatal: unable to access ... Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, git, ventura

i run this in terminal

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/azzammuhammadnaufal/nyoba.git
```

and out this

```
Cloning into 'nyoba'...
```

but, i get this message

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/azzammuhammadnaufal/nyoba.git/': Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

anyone know why i get this message and how to repair it,

THANKS

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you, and finally, I solved it.

First try this:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

and

```
git config --global user.name "yourusername"
git config --global user.email "youremail"
```

if you still get an error, try this next:

i just changed my internet connection using different source instead of my home WiFi;  I  am  using my cellphone hotspot.

The second option solved it for me

Comment: Welcome!  I did an edit to help with the English.  If you need to revert or make changes, please feel free to do so.

Comment: @Allan thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to change the Network connection to my phone

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to explain, more fully, what you mean? You answer isn't very clear.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/338438)